# Why doesn't the dependency resolver throw an error when the Dart SDK version ranges do not match?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter application with an SDK version range of `>=3.1.0 <4.0.0`, which has a dependency on a flutter package which has an SDK version range of `>=2.17.6 <3.0.0`.

Why does this conflict in the SDK version not lead to an error when running `flutter pub get`?

I am using flutter version `3.13.0`

Code:
App pubspec.yaml:

```
...

environment:
  sdk: ">=3.1.0 <4.0.0"

...
```

Package pubspec.yaml

```
...

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=2.5.0"

...
```

I tried using different SDK versions, but the error was only thrown when I used a version <2.12 (before null-safety)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary breaking change in Dart 3 was dropping support for non-null-safe code; almost all code that was null safe was also compatible with Dart 3. Given that, the `pub` resolver special cases any Dart SDK upper bound of `3.0.0` and treats it as `4.0.0` instead.